# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the clientt

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 Order.findById(orderId)
    .then((order) => {
      if (!order) {
        return next(new Error("No order found."));
      }
      if (order.user.userId.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()) {
        return next(new Error("unAuthorized!"));
      }
      const invoiceName = "invoice-" + orderId + ".pdf";
      const invoicePath = path.join("data", "invoices", invoiceName);
      
      const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument();
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
      res.setHeader(
        "Content-Disposition",
        'inline; filename="' + invoiceName + '"'
      );
     
      pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(invoicePath));
      pdfDoc.pipe(res);

      pdfDoc.fontSize(26).text("Invoice", {
        underline: true,
      });
      pdfDoc.text("------------------------");
      let totalPrice = 0;
      order.products.forEach((prod) => {
        totalPrice = totalPrice.prod.quantity * prod.product.price;
        pdfDoc.text(
          prod.product.title +
            " - " +
            prod.quantity +
            " x " +
            " $ " +
            prod.product.price
        );
      });
      pdfDoc.text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

      pdfDoc.end();
```

When i click the link it opens PDF with this error "Failed to load PDF document.
"
And i get this Error on logs 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'

Why is this error occurs can you explain please ?

Comment: You must have already produced some actual _output_ before this (or somehow already explicitly caused the existing headers to sent before.)

Comment: chances are, since this is an asynchronous operation, that the code immediately following this is the problem - the context of this code is important - chances are, `return Order.findById(orderId) ..... etc` will fix it